# Will it be suitable for this kind of application?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

1. 20 CRUD operation UI - create/update/delete
2. WorkFlow Management
3. Dashboard for analysis
4. Report for CRUD and crucial data
5. Report in formats such as csv, pdf etc.,
6. Roles and Permission

Comment: Any suggestions

Comment: Why not try it any find out? It's not like it costs anything to do so